# developing two applications

Tags: android

I want to develop a system for a restaurant, the app will consist of two android applications.
The first is for restaurant employees to get orders and bills from customers and the other is for customers.
Should I generate two different android projects for each app or can I develop the two applications under the same project.

considering that:-

- the two app share a lot of classes and functions that is needed in both
- they share the same firebase database.
- customer app will be uploaded on Google Store
- restaurant app will not uploaded to Google store and will delivered personally

Comment: Two projects, clearly. If one goes to the Store and the other does not, there clearly have to be two separate projects. They can share some of the same code.

Comment: then i should duplicate the shared code in the two apps !?

Comment: for restaurant app just change applicationId in build.gradle

Comment: No. That's the opposite of what I said. **They can share some of the same code** does not mean **I should duplicate the shared code**. When two children share a toy, it does not mean that  the parents run out and buy two of them.

Comment: Here you can do by Adding Product Flavors you can app differenting by thats Flavours generate two packge in one code and diffreneatte

Comment: that is up to you. You may create one project, and 2 modules in it for 2 apps. You even can use a single module, but different build variants (this way I use in my project). Or you can use 2 different projects. All up to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 3 modules in one project :

1. **employees_app**
2. **customers_app**
3. **shared_module**

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module) how to add new module to you project

and to import the shared_module : In ***employees_app/build.gradle*** and ***customers_app/build.gradle***, you should add the shared_module as a dependency:

Example: In ***employees_app/build.gradle*** add the module like that:

```
dependencies {
        compile project(':shared_module')
}
```

But in this case you will have only one APK file mean one application and you should to manage that in your code